# How to get image stream with out saving image using gm module to post the stream data to the another server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get stream of a crop image to send to another service(API) that accepts only stream in post. But, i'm unable to get the stream from gm module. I tried following

```
gm(main.png')
            

    .crop(width, height/6, 0, (height/6)*1)
                    .toBuffer('webp', (err, buffer) => {
                        const { Readable } = require('stream');

                        const readableInstanceStream = new Readable({
                            read() {
                                this.push(binary);
                                this.push(null);
                            }
                        });

                        console.log(readableInstanceStream)
                    });
```

But, that not giving the buffer. So, please help me to get the stream of cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

Using stream(), we can get stream of a image and that can be assign to variable. Following is the example code

```
var cropped_image = gm(main.png')
                .crop(width, height/6, 0, (height/6)*1)
                .stream('png');
```